# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialectMySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsp, jdbc

Im trying to read some table from a database, in a jsp file. It gives me 2 errors, I couldn't find any solution so far searching here around...

Here is the relevant part of the JSP file:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                    <hr>
                    <h2 class="intro-text text-center">
                        Capitolul <strong><%= request.getParameter("capitol") %></strong>
                    </h2>
                    <hr>

                    <hr class="visible-xs">
                    <p id="titles"></p>

                        <%
                                QuestionDAO quest = new QuestionDAO();
                                questions = quest.getQuestions();
                                out.println(questions.size());
                                for(Question q:questions){
                                    out.println(questions.size());
                                    out.println(q.getQuestion());
                                }
                                out.println("Asdfasdf");
                        %>

                </div>
```

Here is the QuestionDAO class:

```
public class QuestionDAO {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(QuestionDAO.class);

    private static SessionFactory factory;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Question> getQuestions(){

        List<Question> q = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Transaction tx=null;

          try{
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                tx = session.beginTransaction();

             Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Question");
             q = query.list();
             System.out.println(q.size()+"!!!");
             for(int i=0; i<q.size(); i++) {
                q.add(q.get(i));
             }
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            } 

          return q;
       }


       public Question addQuestion(Question question) {
            int questionId = -1;
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;
            try {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                questionId = (Integer) session.save(question);
                question.setId(questionId);
                tx.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return question;
        }
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Question findQuestion(int id) {
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;
            List<Question> questions = null;
            try {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Question WHERE id = :id");
                query.setParameter("id", id);
                questions = query.list();
                tx.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return questions != null && !questions.isEmpty() ? questions.get(0) : null;
        }

       public Question deleteQuestion(int id) {
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;
            Question question = (Question)session.load(Question.class, id);
            try {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                session.delete(question);
                tx.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return question;
        }

}
```

THe hibernate cfg file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/licenta</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialectMySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="chapter.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="comments.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="problems.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="questions.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The question hbm(in case its needed):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="models.Question" table="questions">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the questions detail.
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="question" column="question" type="string" />
        <property name="dateAsked" column="date_asked" type="date" />

        <many-to-one name="User" class="models.User"
            column="user_id" not-null="true"
            cascade="all" />

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the error trace is this one:

```
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator: JDBC version : 4.0
aa WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialectMySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
aa ERROR dao.QuestionDAO: 
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at dao.QuestionDAO.getQuestions(QuestionDAO.java:39)
    at org.apache.jsp.forum_002dcapitol_jsp._jspService(forum_002dcapitol_jsp.java:188)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialectMySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 41 more
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl: Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

I mention Im not using Maven. Can you see the problem in here? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a dot(.)

Can you please try with

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Or

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: I think this is going to solve it. I added the dot but for some reason it gives me the same error, like the file was not saved or smth. I opened and reopened eclipse, I created another file and write it again..and same error

Comment: You might be modifying generated class file and not the source file. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: I think this is going to solve it. I added the dot but for some reason it gives me the same error, like the file was not saved or smth. I opened and reopened eclipse, I created another file and write it again..and same error